# Is it safe to remove all the ppa's not checked in other software?

Tags: ppa

I have:

Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-51-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11,5 GiB of RAM

Is it safe to remove all the ppa's not checked in other software?

https://postimg.cc/rDmd7Bps

Thanks!

Comment: No. They used to be enabled, before your last Kubuntu upgrade, and then they were disabled, so that the upgrade wouldn't run into troubles. These PPAs are for software that you've installed at some time, and if you wish to get updates on those apps, then some/all of the PPAs need to be enabled, and the correct repo verified.

Comment: Would say that most programs/PPAs you add yourself are safe to remove. You have to be careful with the programs that come with Ubuntu. Some are tied into other parts of Ubuntu. For removing the PPAs if you are now or in future not expecting to use them, they can be removed, or left alone unless security concern. You will not gain much either way unless you are very short on space on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If asked, I'll revert that to a comment since it is a very general answer to a very general question:

Safe is a relative term that depends on user's needs. Overall you may remove all the repositories your machine knows about (even official OS ones) by any means if you are not planning on using them at all, and add them in the future if you need something from them.
But I would suggest to keep the official OS ones.

The action of Adding or removing a repo does not damage your system itself, but the action of installing something from it may affect it if you're not sure what the package does to it.

Comment: So what are you saying here? It's not clear.

Comment: @crip659 Please see my comment, directly under the original question. Which is probably where your comment should be.

Comment: @heynnema That it is very hard to determine for someone regarding this question "safe" or "not safe" without really knowing this user's machine and considerations. Your on spot comment from personal experience explained the reason the ppas were disabled. I added this answer taking in mind other users will stumble upon it, and also mentioned it can suite as a comment for it is a very general one, considering the question itself was very general.